# Having issue with google cloud setup, keep getting invalid arg type for my key file

Tags: node.js, logging, google-cloud-platform, winston

I am trying to get winston logging working with nodejs, so I have created a new logger, but for some reason it keeps giving me this error. I followed this https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/nodejs step by step as well and cannot seem to find anything else on the internet. I understand the error, the key file is an object and not a string... but then what do I need to do, because JSON.stringify() is not correct either. Also, not looking to set my local env path as this should be working on my servers in heroku.

This is my code:

```
//USED FOR LOGGING
const winston = require('winston');
const gcloud_key = require('../config/gcloud_key.json');

// Imports the Google Cloud client library for Winston
const {LoggingWinston} = require('@google-cloud/logging-winston');

const loggingWinston = new LoggingWinston({
  projectId: config.google_winston.key_id,
  keyFilename: gcloud_key
});
```

This is the error

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received an instance of Object
at validateString (internal/validators.js:120:11)
at Object.resolve (path.js:139:9)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to pass the contents of the service account file to `keyFilename` instead of the filename. The contents is a Dictionary object.

Change this line:

```
keyFilename: gcloud_key
```

To:

```
keyFilename: '../config/gcloud_key.json'
```

Comment: I did that and get this error [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\lior\Desktop\config\gcloud_key.json'] {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\lior\\Desktop\\config\\gcloud_key.json'

Comment: You need to specify the correct filename including the path. Where is the file located on your system? Note: For testing and debugging put the file in the same directory as your program. Once that is working move it to a good location (secure) such as `c:\secrets`.

Comment: As John indicated, you need to provide the full path to the credentials file: https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-logging-winston/blob/master/src/index.ts#L124-L127

Comment: Ok when it is pushed to the server then what am I suppose to be doing? because they wont have access to my file

Comment: Spend some learning about secrets, credentials and how to manage them. They should not be part of your code and should be setup as a separate task. If you are pushing this code to a Google Cloud service such as Compute Engine, you should not be using credentials in a file. You should be using the default service account. Research Application Default Credentials. https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#auth-cloud-implicit-nodejs